# An Honored Tradition

Tags: riddle, game

What does this riddle represent?

> One unbroken chain
>
> Colors fly
>
> One through three, C.A.F.
>
> Merci Pierre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it:

> the Olympics?

One unbroken chain

> The Olympic symbol is one unbroken chain of rings

Colours fly

> The rings are all coloured differently

One Through three, C.A.F.

> unsure

Merci Pierre

> Thank you Pierre de Coubertin (The Frenchman who first proposed and revived what is now the modern Olympic Games)

Comment: Excellent.  Too easy perhaps.